# Why duplicate package name is downloaded from remote repository in pypi?

Tags: python, pip, repository

I have a package that it's name has conflict with a package in the remote repository. When I install the package by the following command:

```
pip install --extra-index-url http://localhost:8070/  my_package
```

It hits to the local repository and then install it from the remote! When I install it directly:

```
sudo pip install http://localhost:8070/packages/my_package-0.1.tar.gz
```

It is installed from local repo successfully. Why pip downloads from the remote? How should I force the pip to install it from the local and give an error in case no local package found? Of course there are some packages that I want to install from the remote `Pypi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal for pip. Extra index appended to default and pip search the highest version. More [info](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3454).

**My solution is proxying pypi.org by nginx.**

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pypi.local;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/repo_pypi.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/repo_pypi.error.log;

    location @to_pypi_org { return 302 https://pypi.org/simple$uri; }

    location / {
        root /var/www/repo_pypi/data;
        allow all;
        autoindex on;
        charset utf-8;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @to_pypi_org;

        location ~ /\.  { deny all; return 404; }
    }
}
```

My repository content location is: `/var/www/repo_pypi/data`
With directory structure as described in Python [docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/).

When nginx couldn't locate any file in my repository then he return temporary redirect to pypi.org repository.

Pip comand is:

```
pip --trusted-host pypi.local --index-url http://pypi.local mypackage
```